# How to verify sender address permission before sending

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I would like to be able to check if the logged in user has permission to send from a specific email address. If he can't I would remove the choice from the UI and he could only send from his.

So far it seems that I can only get the "The user account which was used to submit this request does not have the right to send mail on behalf of the specified sending account." message once I did `.SendAndSaveCopy()`, if I do `.Save()` only it returns no error.

`ImpersonateUserId()` is not enabled on this exchange server.

Answer (score 0):

The SendAS rights is an Extended Active Directory ACE https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ff405676.aspx none of the Mailbox API's can be used view or edit that permission. So the only way you could retrieve this is to query the directory via LDAP and read the DACL on the Target object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no direct way to verify permission.

So I used the below code to "try" to retrieve a list of folders from a given account. If it returns an answer it's because it has permission.

```
private bool HasOwnerAccess(string emailaddress)
    {
        try
        {
            Mailbox mailbox = new Mailbox(emailaddress);
            FindFoldersResults findfolder = exchangeService.FindFolders(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, mailbox), new FolderView(1));
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```